# Making arrows parallel in commutative diagram in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I would simply like to make all the arrows that should be parallel in my commutative square, actually parallel. Here is my diagram:
[image]

The outer square displays functions from the displayed domains and codomains. The inner square (the problem square) displays precisely the action of these functions on elements. I would like all respective lines to be parallel. Also, the right-bottom inner node invades into the outer node. How can I shift this away and get a proper square?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pictexwd,dcpic}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,dsfont,bbm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current  bounding  box.center), scale = 1.5]

\node (homa) at (2, 2) {$\text{hom}_{D}(a, a)$};
\node (homb) at (2,0) {$\text{hom}_{D}(a, b)$};
\node (Ta) at (6, 2) {$Ta$};
\node (Tb) at (6,0) {$Tb$};
\node (id) at (homa.south east) {$1_a$};
\node (f) at (homb.north east) {$f$};
\node (x) at (Ta.south west) {$x$};
\node (Tfx) at (Tb.north west) {$Tf(x)$};
\path[->]
(homa) edge node[left]{$\text{hom}_{D}(a, f)$} (homb)
(Ta) edge node[right] {$Tf$} (Tb)
(homa) edge node[above] {$\tau_a$} (Ta)
(homb) edge node[below] {$\tau_{b}$} (Tb);    
\path[>=stealth,|->] 
(id) edge (f)
(id) edge (x)
(f) edge (Tfx)
(x) edge (Tfx);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I have used the `(node.south west)` prescription to position nodes in the inner square. I do want the nodes of the inner square to be just on the corners of the nodes of the outer square because the nodes of the inner square are members of the respective sets represented as nodes of the outer square.

Answer (score 6):

An example with `tikz-cd`.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[row sep={6mm,between origins},column sep={1cm,between origins}]
hom_{D}(a,a) \arrow[rrrr, "\tau_{a}"] \arrow[ddd, "{hom_{D}(a,f)}", swap] 
    & & & & Ta \arrow[ddd, "Tf"] \\  
    & 1_{a} \arrow[rr, |->] \arrow[d, |->] & & x \arrow[d, |->] & \\[1cm]
    & f \arrow[rr, |->] & & Tf(x) \\
hom_{D}(a,b) \arrow[rrrr, "\tau_{b}", swap] & & & & Tb\\  
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

For commutative diagrams I always use [tikz's](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) `\matrix` command together with `matrix of math nodes`. This gives an easy way of placing the nodes of your diagram into an array and then drawing lines between the nodes. To use this you need to have

```
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
```

in your preamble. The basic idea is something like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
  \matrix (M)[matrix of math nodes,row sep=1cm,column sep=16mm]{
     A&B\\
     C&D\\
   };
   \draw[->](M-1-1)--(M-1-2)--(M-2-2)--(M-2-1)--(M-1-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which produces:

[image]

So you refer to the nodes as `(M-<row>-<col>)`. The `M` is the first argument `(M)` to `\matrix`. You can make this whatever you like.

Normally the separation of the rows and columns, which is controlled by `row sep=1cm,column sep=16mm`, is constant for all rows and columns (again, choose the values to suit). For the OPs diagram we need to vary the spacing a little, which you can do with optional arguments inside the matrix as shown below. It is also good to specify that you want the row and column distances `between origins` as this leads to better spacing. The end result is:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,->,shorten >=2pt,looseness=.5,auto]
      \matrix (M)[matrix of math nodes,row sep={6mm,between origins},
                                       column sep={6mm,between origins}]{
        \hom_{D}(a, a)&      &[28mm] &  Ta\\% 28mm=extra space between cols 2&3
                      &  1_a & x     &    \\[16mm]% extra space between rows 2&3
                      &    f & Tf    &   \\
        \hom_{D}(a, a)&      &       & Tb\\
       };
       \draw[->](M-1-1)--node{$\tau_a$}(M-1-4);
       \draw[->](M-4-1)--node[below]{$\tau_b$}(M-4-4);
       \draw[->](M-1-1)--node[left]{$\hom_D(a,f)$}(M-4-1);
       \draw[->](M-1-4)--node{$Tf$}(M-4-4);
       % inner square
       \draw[|->](M-2-2)--(M-2-3);
       \draw[|->](M-3-2)--(M-3-3);
       \draw[|->](M-2-2)--(M-3-2);
       \draw[|->](M-2-3)--(M-3-3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Notice that I use `\hom` rather than `\text{hom}` for the hom-spaces. I have also used "stealth" arrows because I like them better.

Comment: Is there any reason why I should not *always* choose tikz-cd over a solution like this (no offense intended)?

Comment: +1 for the `between origins` key. I didn't know about it, very convenient!

Comment: @Danu I find the syntax of `tikz-cd` somewhat ungainly, but it is certainly more concise. Whatever makes you happy:)